# When to use exceptions in django

Tags: django, try-catch

What are the important queries when developers should use try catch block.

For Example, getting an object must be in try block.

```
Person.objects.get(pk=12)
```

Comment: Your question is too broad and opinion based. why "must" getting an object be in a try block?.

Comment: @Sayse because it may cause the error

Comment: Every time you walk down a flight of stairs you could fall, does that mean you need to hold the hand rail every time?

Comment: @Sayse I just want that my code don't crash.. It should return some error. But i can't afford site crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly.

When to use exception :

When you think a particular piece of code can through an error if some 
   certain criteria not match.

for example :`Person.objects.get(pk=12)`

In above query what if Person having id 12 not present in DB this situation can cause a possible error so you have to handle this in catch block.
Same way what if some one opening a file which does not exist.What if a person trying get a list value which does not exist.

these are some case like this their are many possibilities.

Note : NO one can tell you what are the important queries, you should analysis them yourself and see the possibilities of throwing error.
This has nothing to do with Django or any other framework.

Answer (score -2):

Try-catch block helps in catching Exceptions, these are application-to-OS wide events that are "lookouts" for Erroneous events.

I think most try-catch block is used for Resources monitoring, like open files, memory issues, etc., it lets the code reacts on erroneous events during execution, so its more reliable than branching statements.